# Customize the version string for an Elastic Beanstalk application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

I have an Elastic Beanstalk application that is automatically deployed via CodeCommit-CodeBuild-CodePipeline.

After I deploy, the "Running version" looks like this:

[image: Running version string in Elastic Beanstalk]

I would like to customize it to display a string taken from the `VERSION` file in my repository along with a timestamp or something like that.

Is there any way to achieve this?